# Model-view-control and swing gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

I've a doubt. I don't know where insert each  eventlistener in a pattern MVC. Is it right to insert them in a controller or is better insert eventlistener directly in view?And from view eventlistener can call a controller to do something.

Comment: Better in the controller , from view eventlistener can call a controller but there is probability of some  mixing  mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event listeners should be in the controller. The controller holds an instance of the view and your view has public methods to set the event listeners of the GUI controls(JTextField etc).

Example: You have a view that has a `JButton` control called `buttonSubmit` and you want to listen for when someone interacts with that button.

**View**

```
public void addSubmitButtonListener(ActionListener listener) {
    buttonSubmit.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public void run() {
    view.addSubmitButtonListener( new SubmitButtonListener() );
}

class SubmitButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // What happens after someone interacts with the button goes in here.
    }

}
```

That `SubmitButtonListener` class goes directly into the controller as an inner class.